# Mint + windows 10 dual boot

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I have dual booting mint + windows 10. I have a problem with displaying this table after starting the computer:

[image]

I tried to star linux and use

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdx
```

Then, the choice appears after starting the computer. However, when I chose the 3rd option (Winudows), the choice does not appears anymore. Then I need start Linux via boot menu. How to solve that, please?

Which path should I choose? This is my dev directory:

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure `/dev/sdx` is the correct device? It seems unlikely that you have that many drives attached (naming follows the alphabet, starting with `sda`).

Comment: How to make sure that the device is correct, please? Where the path should aim to?

Comment: type ```lsblk``` and search for "/" at the end of line. That is your root partition. 
Example: ```└─sdb3   8:19   0 452,6G  0 part /```. Grub may be in EFI partition, look for something like "/boot/efi" at the end of line

Comment: Thank; thus, I used: `sudo grub-install /boot/efi` . I turned on windows, switched it off, and when the computer started, there was no choice and windows started immediately again.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/